# Hooking up front end to back end WebAPI in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a front end which makes requests to a back end WebAPI, I've 'published' both through Visual Studio to the Azure account and can see them under 'All resources' as 'App Service'.

So because I've been running both projects on my local machine making http requests from the frontend to the WebAPI (both through typescript/react-redux and C# controller functions) I have localhost:XXXX root addresses followed by the api path (i.e. api/something?dude)

On Azure obviously all this changes.

How do I set it up so that the frontend 'knows' how to call the WebAPI without needing to say change certain values repeatedly in both C# and react-redux typescript code?

Comment: Hmm not sure what about my question was unclear, perhaps if people commented specifically on what they were unclear on instead of just downvoting and trying to close the question it would have been helpful :) Oh well, in the end I came up with my own solution to the problem inc ase anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good solution to this problem:

In my appsettings.json for my frontend I added the URL of my WebAPI, in appsettings.development.json this was 'localhost:XXXX' and in appsettings.live.json it's 'mywebapiurl.com'.

In C# I grabbed the value from the configuration based on the build configuration (i.e. if it's a live build grab appsettings.live.json). So now everything works seemlessly between my local build and the azure site after deployment.